# Exterior powers of the Cartan matrix and Dyck paths

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, homological-algebra

(This question can be formulated purely combinatorially in terms of Dyck paths, which is done in the second part of the question. But I am more interested whether this can be explained by some sort of derived equivalence and maybe a modification of the defintion of $O_A$).

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $K$-algebra of finite global dimension with Cartan matrix $C$ that is of size $n \times n$. Let $S(M)$ denote the sum of all entries of a matrix $M$ and $\bigwedge^i(C)$ the $\binom{n}{i} \times \binom{n}{i}$-matrix acting on $\bigwedge^i(V)$ when $C: V \rightarrow V$ for a vector space $V \cong K^n$.

Define the invariant $O_A:= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{ S(\bigwedge^i C)}$ and the list $L_A:=[S(\bigwedge^1 C),....,S(\bigwedge^n C)]$.

> Question 1: It seems that for linear quadratic Nakayama algebras with $n$ simples this $O_A$ is an invariant (tested for $n \leq 9$). Is this true?

Here an example: The Nakayama algebra $A$ with Kupisch series [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 ] has $L_A=[ 11, 45, 84, 70, 21, 1 ]$ and the Nakayama algebra $B$ with Kupisch series [ 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 ] has $L_B=[ 12, 50, 89, 65, 15, 1 ]$. Those lists are quite different but have the same sum.

Note that linear quadratic Nakayama algebras with $n$ simples are all derived equivalent. But in general $O_A$ is not a derived invariant for more general algebras. However, often derived equivalent algebras have the same $O_A$ (tested at least for Nakayama algebras. Another example is the incidence algebra of the Boolean lattice of a 2-set(here $L_A=[ 9, 12, 3, 1 ]$), which is derived equivalent to a path algebra of Dynkin type $D_4$ (here $L_A=[ 9, 10, 5, 1 ]$) where both algebras have $O_A=25$).

> Question 2: Is there a modification of the definition $O_A$ that gives a derived invariant for general finite dimensional algebra of finite global dimension? Maybe the invariants also depends on coming from a special derived equivalence like maybe coming from some special tilting modules.

---

Question 1 has a purely combinatorial/linear algebraic formulation for Dyck paths that is as follows:

A Dyck path of length $n$ is a list of positive integers $[c_1,c_2,...,c_n]$ with $c_i -1 \leq c_{i+1}$ for all $i$ and $c_i \geq 2$ for $i \neq n$ and $c_n=1$.
(One can show that those sequences really correspond to the classical Dyck paths via the area sequence and the number of Dyck paths of length $n$ is $C_{n-1}$ when $C_n$ denotes the Catalan numbers)

Let $D=[c_1,c_2,...,c_n]$ be a Dyck path of length $n$.
We define the Cartan matrix $C_D$ of $D$ as the $n \times n$ upper triangular matrix with entries 0 or 1 as follows:
In the $i$-th row $C_D$ has entries equal to one in position $(i,i)$, $(i,i+1)$,...,$(i,i+c_i-1)$ and all other entries are zero.

For example the Cartan matrix of $[2,5,4,3,3,2,1]$ is given by

\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}

Call a Dyck path bouncing when the it is of the form $[m_1,m_1-1,m_1-2,....,3,2,m_2,m_2-1,...,2,....,m_l,m_l-1,....,2,1]$, which means that the picture of the Dyck path is a bouncing Dyck path (meaning it consists only of Dyck paths of the form u^l d^l glued together at the x-axis).

> Question 1': Do the Cartan matrices $C$ of bouncing Dyck paths have the property that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{ S(\bigwedge^i C)}$ is independent of the bouncing Dyck path?

It seems that for bouncing Dyck paths $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{ S(\bigwedge^i C)}$ is given by $F_{2n+1}-1$ (https://oeis.org/A027941).